# Java-based i18n/L10n

Tags: java, internationalization

I've seen internationalization implemented in a classic ASP shopping cart as a **most-massive** monolithic dictionary of (int,String) key-value pairs, where the calling code passed the dictionary an integer representing which string was to be returned (binary-ORed with the desired language id) and the value for each unique int was the "internationalized" string.

This seems like a very, very, very horrible way to implement i18n.

I'm in the "pre-design" (if there is such a thing) phase for a Java-based Swing application that I would want to be internationalized. Not that I speak anything other than English (ha!) but it would be nice to expand into other languages in the future without having to refactor 20,000 strings.

So, this begs the question: **what are the best practices surrounding Java-based i18n (and L10n for that matter)?** What sort of classes & structures are used? Obviously, if this winds up as one big *com.myproject.i18n* package with an "Internationalizer" class as the common gateway for the rest of my code, I would want this to be a singleton class, yes?

Just a request for some food-for-thought here, any nudges in the right direction are greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to work around properties files. They are easy to work with and you can extend this system easily.

You can find a nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902031/how-to-implement-multilanguage-in-java-swing-applications). 
Netbeans have also a great sample [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-automatic-i18n.html). 

After you get your languages right, you will need [software](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html) to switch locales, localize dates and amounts etc. Kai Toedter' tools are very reliable. You can add these beans to your IDE and drag and drop them to your JPanels.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your property file and insert them into [iL10Nz](http://www.myl10n.net).

In order to evoid context issues, it is good to have a scrrenshot for each strings that you are progressively creating. This will pay off with the languages you will translate into

Check http://www.myl10n.net

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Gettext Commons](http://code.google.com/p/gettext-commons/). It's i18n in [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/)-way for Java. It has Maven plugin for generating, updating and compiling PO files. Personally after some time of use found it's easier to go with standard ResourceBundles.

Answer (score 0):

i using netbeans for developing GUI application based on Swing Application Framework [SAF]

and you can get powerful tools for internationalizing Project on Netbeans IDE.

look at this article : [Internationalizing a GUI Form](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-automatic-i18n.html)